# List files in different (non-working) directory with wildcard

Tags: ls, wildcards

I'm trying to list all files in */etc* that has only 2 characters before the first period, and not include sub-directories and their content.

I'm using:

```
ls -d ??.*
```

and it is working just as I want, but when I try to do it from another directory I can't get it to work. I have tried

```
ls -d /etc ??.*
```

and

```
ls -d ??.* /etc
```

But I get the same error

```
ls: cannot access ??.*: No such file or directory
```

This is for a school assignment, so using find or anything other than ls is not an option. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the man pages before posting a question. I believe it clearly explains that `-d` has a different purpose.

Comment: @Bram, if any of the `??.*` are directories, `-d` does prevent listing their contents. Though of course, it still lists the directories themselves. But since this was a school assignment, I'm not sure if it's necessary to work around that, at least with the level of accuracy usual to unix.SE. :)

Answer (score 9):

`ls` does not take a *separate* directory argument.

To match files in a specific directory, you can simply prepend the directory path to your glob pattern:

```
ls -d /etc/??.*
/etc/ld.so.cache  /etc/ld.so.conf  /etc/ld.so.conf.d  /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: @PerKristianPettersen If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.